# Explaining of the work of physics::JointController

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm want to use PID in my plugin. I use common::PID and it's work fine, and I see that JointController use PID too. But I have problem with compiling plugin with JointController. I think I'm don't understand how to work with explicit constructors. Can anyone show a simple example ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12683/explaining-of-the-work-of-physics::jointcontroller/) by [Aiven92](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2471/aiven92/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From a model plugin, you can get a pointer to the model's `JointController` with:

```
this->model->GetJointController()
```

See an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/robocup3ds/src/91d23ea318e5efd6bc8b4ec2c423ecb3adc1110e/src/Robocup3dsPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Robocup3dsPlugin.cc-390)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0